# Custom Pop Up Menu Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

Any Idea About How to Get Pop menu like this.

UI in Flutter.

[Pop Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccY5k.png)

We could try stack but it needed to be in out of its stack boundary

Comment: can you please provide some more information?

Comment: There is a button in the app bar . When you click on the icon, it will show a pop up menu. what i need is the popupmenu item should be something like the image shown above.If the image is not clear please ping me.

Comment: can you please send the image again?

Comment: Image Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZrJ6BRaKeCT42cOlimK3W-tBH37X5My/view?usp=sharing